# How to convert a Character Key into a String output from a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

`lst = [and, and, and, and, these, those, their, boxes, boxes]`

```
 public Collection<Character> mostCommonFirstWeighted() {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
            for (String s : lst) {
            if (hashmap.get(s.charAt(0)) == null) {
                hashmap.put(s.charAt(0), 1);
            } else {
                hashmap.put(s.charAt(0), hashmap.get(s.charAt(0)).intValue() + 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hashmap);
```

`hashmap = {a=4, b=2, t=3}`

Now how can I get my hashmap to return the key(s) with the highest correlation values only.

Desired output:

`[a]`

Comment: How is possible this method with `lst`returns `{a=4, b=2, t=3}`? Shouln't be `{t=2, q=1, b=2, f=1, j=1, o=1, l=1, d=1}` ?

Comment: Sorry was using the wrong list example. I just edited it

Comment: "Correlation value"? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One  way could be:

```
Collection<Integer> values = hashmap.values(); // get values
List<Integer> listVal = new ArrayList<Integer>(values); 
Collections.sort(listVal, new Comparator<Integer>() { // sort in decreasing order 
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return - o1.compareTo(o2); 
    }
});

Integer maxVal = listVal.get(0); // get first (max value)

Collection<Character> returns = new ArrayList<Character>(); 

for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : hashmap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().intValue() == maxVal.intValue()) { 
        returns.add(entry.getKey());  // get all keys that matches maxVal
    }
}

return returns;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked great

Answer (score 0):

You mean just the entries with the values that occur most?

```
int max = 0;
    Collection<Character> c = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e: hashmap.entrySet()) {
        int v = e.getValue();
        if (v >= max) {
            if (v > max) {
                c.clear();
                max = v;
            }
            c.add(e.getKey());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(c);  
    return c;
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to return all character keys in the hashtable..  [a, b, t]

Comment: I don't think so. I actually tested it here locally.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you want to print the values in the same method, so you could try this. I haven't tested it nor compared it against a compiler, might need a few tweaks here and there...

```
if ( !hashmap.isEmpty() ) {
     Set<Character> chars = hashmap.keys();
     Iterator<Character> rator = chars.interator();
     Integer max = hashmap.get( (Character)chars.toArray()[0] );
     Integer tmp;
     while( rator.hasNext() ) {
           tmp = hashmap.get( (Character)rator.next() );
           if ( tmp >= max ) 
                 rator.remove()
     }
     System.out.println(chars); }
```

Comment: There is no `keys()` method in `HashMap`. It is `keyset()`. And your code does not return `[a]`

Comment: Good eye, pal. Again, i did warn for reserve if copy-pasting.